# How to send values from fragment to viewmodel (Repository)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I am working on an MVVM architecture-based app where I have a value that users select on the fragment which I have to update in the API call request that I am making in the RepositoryImpl class using LiveData, how could I do this?

```
class Fragment1 : ScopedFragment(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by closestKodein()
    private val viewModelFactory: Fragment1ViewModelFactory by instance()

    private lateinit var viewModel: Fragment1ViewModel

    private var selected1 = ""
    private var selected2 = ""
    private var selected3 = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(Fragment1ViewModel::class.java)
        bindUI()
        }

        setSpinner1()
        setSpinner2()

        setButton.setOnClickListener {
            val modalbottomSheetFragment = MyBottomSheetDialogFragment()
            modalbottomSheetFragment.show(parentFragmentManager, modalbottomSheetFragment.tag)
        }

    }

    private fun bindUI() = launch {
        valueContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val currentValue = viewModel.fragment1
        currentValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it == null) return@Observer
            value.text = it.Val
        })
        comboSelected = selected1 + selected2
    }
```

**comboSelected** is the value that I have to pass to the repository so that I could fetch the value of the selected value pair.

Repository Code -

```
class NameRepositoryImpl(
    private val NameValueDao: NameValueDao,
    private val NameNetworkDataSource: NameNetworkDataSource
) : NameRepository {

    init {
        NameNetworkDataSource.downloadedName.observeForever { newNameValue ->
            persistFetchedNameValue(newNameValue)
        }
    }

    private val value: Flow<NameResponseDB> = NameValueDao.getNameValue()

    override suspend fun getCurrentValue() {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            initNameData()
        }
    }

    override fun getCurrentNameValue(): Flow<NameResponseDB> {
        return value
    }

    private fun persistFetchedNameValue(nameValue: NameResponse) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            NameValueDao.upsert(
                NameResponseDB(
                    valueCode = NameValue.valueCode,
                    nameVal = NameValue.nameVal
                )
            )
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initNameData() {
        if (isFetchNameNeeded(ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30)))
            fetchNameValue()
    }

    private suspend fun fetchNameValue() {
        NameNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentValue(valueCode = "**Need the combo Selected Value here**")
        val value = NameNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentValue(valueCode = "**Need the combo Selected Value here**")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `Kodein` specifically but I have used `Dependency Injection` with `MVVM` using `Koin` and also `Dagger Hilt`, so the basic idea should still remain the same here as well.

You need to provide an instance of your `repository` to the `viewModel`, and remove `private` from that function `fetchNameValue` so that `viewModel` can call this `suspend fun` via the `viewmodelscope`. Also, `viewModel` and `repository` are not the same thing. You should create their logic separately. So it should be like this:

> Fragment

```
private fun bindUI() = launch {
    valueContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val currentValue = viewModel.fragment1
    currentValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (it == null) return@Observer
        value.text = it.Val
    })
    comboSelected = selected1 + selected2
    viewModel.doSomething(comboSelected)
}
```

> ViewModel

```
class MyVm(
 private val repository: Repository          // inject respository
): ViewModel() {

    fun doSomething(value: String) {

         viewModelScope.launch {
         repository.fetchNameValue(value)
         }
    }
}
```

> Repository

```
class Repository {

    suspend fun fetchNameValue(nameValue: String) {
    NameNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentValue(valueCode = nameValue)
    val value = NameNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentValue(valueCode = nameValue)
}
}
```

If you still have a doubt, let me know, I'll try to update my answer :)

Comment: Understood, the issue was with the repository being unable to fetch the value from the viewModel. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Great to hear you found the solution! :)